# Adding space between textfield character when typing in text filed

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a `textfield` with maximum character range 16, After every 4 characters, I want to add minus character or space and then writing The rest of the characters like this sample 5022-2222-2222-2222. 
there is my code but that's don't work, how can do this?

```
if textField.text?.characters.count  == 5 {

               let  l = textField.text?.characters.count
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cartNumberTextField.text!)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: CGFloat(4.0), range: NSRange(location: l!, length: 4))
            cartNumberTextField.attributedText = attributedString

            }

            else if textField.text?.characters.count  == 9 {

                let  l = textField.text?.characters.count
                let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cartNumberTextField.text!)
                attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: CGFloat(4.0), range: NSRange(location: l!, length: 4))
                cartNumberTextField.attributedText = attributedString

            }

            else if textField.text?.characters.count  == 13 {

                let  l = textField.text?.characters.count
                let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cartNumberTextField.text!)
                attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: CGFloat(4.0), range: NSRange(location: l!, length: 4))
                cartNumberTextField.attributedText = attributedString

            }
```

I am adding this code in `UITextField` `shouldChangeCharactersIn` range method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We may start by implementing a Swift 3 version of the [`chunk(n:)` method](https://github.com/oisdk/SwiftSequence/blob/master/Sources/ChunkWindowSplit.swift) (for `Collection`'s) of oisdk:s [SwiftSequence](https://github.com/oisdk/SwiftSequence):

```
/* Swift 3 version of Github use oisdk:s SwiftSequence's 'chunk' method:
   https://github.com/oisdk/SwiftSequence/blob/master/Sources/ChunkWindowSplit.swift */
extension Collection {
    public func chunk(n: IndexDistance) -> [SubSequence] {
        var res: [SubSequence] = []
        var i = startIndex
        var j: Index
        while i != endIndex {
            j = index(i, offsetBy: n, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
            res.append(self[i..<j])
            i = j
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

In which case implementing your custom formatting is a simple case of creating 4-character chunks and joining these by "-":

```
func customStringFormatting(of str: String) -> String {
    return str.characters.chunk(n: 4)
        .map{ String($0) }.joined(separator: "-")
}
```

Example usage:

```
print(customStringFormatting(of: "5022222222222222")) // 5022-2222-2222-2222
print(customStringFormatting(of: "50222222222222"))   // 5022-2222-2222-22
print(customStringFormatting(of: "5022222"))          // 5022-222
```

---

If applying to be used in the [`textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield) method of `UITextFieldDelegate`, we might want to filter out existing separators in the `customStringFormatting(of:)` method method, as well as implementing it as a `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    func chunkFormatted(withChunkSize chunkSize: Int = 4, 
        withSeparator separator: Character = "-") -> String {
        return characters.filter { $0 != separator }.chunk(n: chunkSize)
            .map{ String($0) }.joined(separator: String(separator))
    }
}
```

And implement the controlled updating of the textfield e.g. as follows:

```
let maxNumberOfCharacters = 16

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // only allow numerical characters
    guard string.characters.flatMap({ Int(String($0)) }).count ==
        string.characters.count else { return false }

    let text = textField.text ?? ""

    if string.characters.count == 0 {
        textField.text = String(text.characters.dropLast()).chunkFormatted()
    }
    else {
        let newText = String((text + string).characters
            .filter({ $0 != "-" }).prefix(maxNumberOfCharacters))
        textField.text = newText.chunkFormatted()
    }
    return false
}
```

The last part above will truncate possible pasted strings from the user (given that it's all numeric), e.g.

```
// current 
1234-1234-123

// user paste:
777777777
  /* ^^^^ will not be included due to truncation */  

// will result in
1234-1234-1237-7777
```

Comment: my textfield is showing each entered number twice, one is because of keyboard stroke and other is by assigning textField.text = newText.chunkFormatted()

Comment: @AshWineeDhakad This answer is 5+ years old, and based (IIRC) on Swift 2. We're at Swift 5 now? I don't do Swift anymore, but feel free to update this answer to address modern Swift.

Answer (score 6):

Use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` like this way.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if [6, 11, 16].contains(textField.text?.count ?? 0) && string.isEmpty {
        textField.text = String(textField.text!.dropLast())
        return true
    }
    let text = NSString(string: textField.text ?? "").replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string).replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
    if text.count >= 4 && text.count <= 16 {
        var newString = ""
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: text.count, by: 4) {
            let upperBoundIndex = i + 4
            let lowerBound = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: i)
            let upperBound = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: upperBoundIndex)
            if upperBoundIndex <= text.count  {
                newString += String(text[lowerBound..<upperBound]) + "-"
                if newString.count > 19 {
                   newString = String(newString.dropLast())
                }
            }
            else if i <= text.count {
                newString += String(text[lowerBound...])
            }
        }
        textField.text = newString
        return false
    }
    if text.count > 16 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**Note:** I have used `- (Hyphen)` you can simply replace it with `Space` if you want `Space` instead of `- (Hyphen)`.

**Edit:** Code is edited to latest swift 4.*, for older swift version please check edit history.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I have tried with solution is working perfectly for deleting, also i have changed code to latest swift. If you still facing issue can you make one video and provide me link so i get more idea. Thanks

Comment: I deleted the middle characters. Not from the last

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I have edited answer to delete characters from middle, But i personally prefer use dfri's answer

Comment: Not able to delete the characters, only last 4 can be deleted. Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 4):

To do it "on the fly", I connected Editing changed to this IBAction ; needs also to care for backspace

```
 @IBAction func editingTestField(_ sender: UITextField) {
      if sender.text!.count > 0 && sender.text!.count % 5 == 0 && sender.text!.last! != "-" {
         sender.text!.insert("-", at:sender.text!.index(sender.text!.startIndex, offsetBy: sender.text!.count-1) )
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Took @claude31's simple solution and cleaned it up a bit. Also avoids issues with leading/trailing whitespace now. Just hook it up to your UITextField's **Editing Changed** event.

```
@IBAction func editingTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let text = sender.text?.trim ?? ""
    if !text.isEmpty && text.count % 5 == 0 && text.last != "-" {
        sender.text = text  // trim whitespace before appending
        sender.text?.insert("-", at: text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: text.count - 1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift-5 conversion of @dfrib's answer.

```
extension Collection {
    public func chunk(n: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        var res: [SubSequence] = []
        var i = startIndex
        var j: Index
        while i != endIndex {
            j = index(i, offsetBy: n, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
            res.append(self[i..<j])
            i = j
        }
        return res
    }
}
```