# How to make UITextField input like credit card (xxxx-xxxx-xxxx) type text in swift3

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to create credit card type text with following code, but not able to do that, is there any way to do?

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.groupingSize = 4
    formatter.groupingSeparator = "-"
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    print("txtCardNumber \(txtCardNumber.text)")
}
```

Comment: For me the nicest way is to create your own component. Just group 4 textfields with 4 characters max. length each and set the UI to make it look like a single one. 

You can also make the next one becomeFirstResponder() when the previous is 4 char long and resignFirstResponder() when filling the last one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding space between textfield character when typing in text filed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946134/adding-space-between-textfield-character-when-typing-in-text-filed)