# How to put TextField`s content type for Float on XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, content-type

I've a TextField to user put a number value (Float or Double), but in most of cases it number is Integer, but I must show the value in Float format for example: `3.0`, `2.5`. When the user put a Integer, the value shows like: `2`. How I set a way to TextField automatically put in decimal point value?
ps. In the options of content type not have a option to number.

[image]

This is the wrong way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbox solution, you should do it manually with `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   //customize your string here
}
```

Comment: What means "inbox solution" ?

Comment: Resolved by Apple, with their open API. For example in storyboard you don't see possible state for quick problem solving.

Comment: You can check a similar problem but with "-" character: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40946134/1278744

Comment: The documention says: "Asks the delegate if the specified text should be changed. " . But isn't this that I need. At: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield

Comment: It's exactly what youu need becouse of there you get old textfield text and new and you can add or remove this additional character. For example if you see that your prev text lenght is 3 and there is one more number is adding you add "." and that number. So as a result you will get line with all numbers and dot.

Comment: This function handler one character for time, this not helps me, I can't know when user put all data

Comment: Exactly, you verify entering and removing numbers that allow to customize each future changing.

Comment: Also you should be familiar with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event