# Adding hyphen between textfield character when typing in text filed

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift4

I have a textfield with maximum character range 7, After 3 characters, I want to add minus character and then writing The rest of the characters like this sample 555-5555. Here is my code but that's don't work, how can I fix this?

```
// MARK: -UITextField Action

    @objc func textFieldDidChanged(_ textField:UITextField ){
        //print(PlaceTextField.text!)
        if(textField.text?.count == 4){
                if(textField.text?.contains("-"))!{
                    textField.text!.removeLast()
                    textField.text!.removeLast()
                }
            }
            if(textField.text?.count == 3){
                print("-\n")
               textField.text = textField.text! + "-"
            }
    }
```

I tried to solve from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946134/adding-space-between-textfield-character-when-typing-in-text-filed) but not working properly.

Comment: You should handle this in `shouldChangeCharacters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you do not copy paste text to the text field.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = textField.text, let textRange = Range(range, in: text) {
        let updatedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: string)
        if textField.text?.count == 3 && updatedText.count == 4 {
            textField.text = textField.text! + "-" + string
            return false
        }
        if textField.text?.count == 5 && updatedText.count == 4 {
            let text = textField.text!
            textField.text = String(text.prefix(3))
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

P.S - Your text field keyboard should be number pad.

```
yourTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my approach from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ZalyalovIldar/7588bb2758bb871fe0c036e1ece3fc8e). It's allow you create your own pattern for phone number or anything else and just use. Hope it's help!